# converting json branched array to php object

Tags: php, arrays, json

In below code, I want to display `get_data` using `echo` but not able to decode/display branched array. So, My question is how to convert branched array to PHP object.

**Json Response :**

```
{"status":1,"msg":"fetched Succesfully","user_data":{"d91c2d21af80002a3dd6ffc76f62bb9f89b6e0ba":{"name":"PRATYUSH","user_year":"2013","get_data":"d91c2d21af80002a3dd6ffc76f62bb9f89b6e0ba","is_active":1,"data_no":"ghjgjj2XXXXXXoioo7","user_bin":"77","is_exp":"N"}}}
```

**PHP CODE :**(after using curl)

```
$response = json_decode($o,true);
$status=$response["status"];
$msg=$response["msg"];
$user_data=$response["user_data"][0]["get_data"];
```

**RESULT:**

```
echo $status;//(working)
echo "<br>";
echo $msg;//(working)
echo "<br>";
echo $user_data;//(Not working)
```

`echo User_data` is not working.

Comment: What is the decoded json data in $response?

Comment: Its a 'array'........

Comment: I mean to ask, did you get your result in such a way?? 

> Array(
 ["status"] => '1',
 ["msg"] => "fetched Succesfully",
 ["user_data"] => Array(
   ["d91c2d21af80002a3dd6ffc76f62bb9f89b6e0ba"] => Array(
       ["name"] => "PRATYUSH",
       ["user_year"] => "2013",
       ["get_data"] => "d91c2d21af80002a3dd6ffc76f62bb9f89b6e0ba",
       ["is_active"] => 1,
       ["data_no"] => "ghjgjj2XXXXXXoioo7",
       ["user_bin"] => "77",
       ["is_exp"] => "N"
      )
   )

)

Comment: @abhishek-Thanks, its working.

Comment: @abhishek What to do when there is more than one get_data in at json response? Like below {"status":1,"msg":"fetched Succesfully","user_data":{"d91c2d21af80002a3dd6ffc76f62bb9f89b6e0ba":{"name":"PRATYUSH","user_year":"2013","get_data":"d91c2d21af80002a3dd6ffc76f62bb9f89b6e0ba","is_active":1,"data_no":"ghjgjj2XXXXXXoioo7","user_bin":"77","is_exp":"N"},"ty6c2d21af80002a3dd6ffc76f62bb9f89b6e0ba":{"name":"PghfghH","user_year":"2015","get_data":"ty6c2d21af80002a3dd6ffc76f62bb9f89b6e0ba","is_active":1,"data_no":"ghjgjj2XXXXXXoioo7","user_bin":"77","is_exp":"N"}}}

Comment: @user3588059 in this case, you can run the given code and store `get_data` value in an array. for eg. `$user_data[] = $user_data_obj['get_data'];`. and replace `$user_data="";` with `$user_data=array();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to get value of `get_data`. If `d91c2d21af80002a3dd6ffc76f62bb9f89b6e0ba` is not known, try this way.

```
$user_data_arr=$response["user_data"]; 
foreach($user_data_arr AS $user_data_obj)
{
    echo $user_data_obj['get_data'];// here is your desired value
}
```

Using `foreach` loop, you do not have to find index and you can get values easily.

**Full Code**

```
 $response = json_decode($o,true);
 $status=$response["status"];
 $msg=$response["msg"];
 $user_data="";
 $user_data_arr=$response["user_data"]; 
  foreach($user_data_arr AS $user_data_obj)
  {
    $user_data = $user_data_obj['get_data'];// here is your desired value
  }
 echo $status;
 echo "<br>";
 echo $msg;
 echo "<br>";
 echo $user_data;//will work
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

`$user_data=$response["user_data"][0]["get_data"];`

to this

`$user_data=$response["user_data"]["d91c2d21af80002a3dd6ffc76f62bb9f89b6e0ba"]["get_data"];`

Comment: "d91c2d21af80002a3dd6ffc76f62bb9f89b6e0ba" comes in json response part, I can't use this value.